# c# dictionary select value from key

Tags: c#, dictionary

I've been searching through here and I realize that similar questions have been asked before, and I've gone over several, but what seems to be correct doesn't seem to be working for.

I have the following method which pulls a set of key value pairs in a DataSet gathered from a SQL query.

```
    public static Dictionary<string, string> LoadConfiguration()
    {
        DataSet sqlResults = data.GetSettings();

        Dictionary<string, string> dict = 
            new Dictionary<String, String>();

        foreach (DataRow dr in sqlResults.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            dict.Add(
                dr.Field<string>("key"), dr.Field<string>("value")
                    );
        }

        return dict;
    }
```

It's as simple as it gets as far as I can see, but I've never actually worked with a dictionary before as I'm relatively new to any kind of real programming.

I know that my Dictionary has the expected data, because if I iterate through it with a foreach, it gives me the expected results

```
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> i in MyStuff.Configuration.LoadConfiguration())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Key = " + i.Key + " Value = " + i.Value);
    }
```

which gives me the following which is all I've implemented so far

> Key = EnableLdap Value = false
>   Key = LdapPath Value = LDAP://DC=some,DC=domain,DC=com 
>   Key = SessionTimeout Value = 60

But I only want to select a specific value from a key named EnableLdap for example

My understanding is that both the following methods would be correct. But when I try this way, I get a KeyNotFoundException

```
    Dictionary<string,string> dict = MyStuff.Configuration.LoadConfiguration();
    Console.WriteLine(dict["EnableLdap"]);
```

If I try this I get a [InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element]

```
    Dictionary<string,string> dict = MyStuff.Configuration.LoadConfiguration();
    Console.WriteLine(dict.Single(s => s.Key == "EnableLdap").Value);
```

And if I try this I just get nothing

```
    string value = "";

    if (dict.TryGetValue("EnableLdap", out value))
    {
        dict["EnableLdap"] = value;
        Console.WriteLine(value);

    }
```

I'm pretty certain I'm missing something simple here and the answer will result in a facepalm

SOLUTION:

I got caught by trailing spaces as was suggested a few times in the comments. The solution was to simply add some trimming to my row values when adding them to my Dictionary.

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> LoadConfiguration()
{
    DataSet sqlResults = data.GetSettings();

    Dictionary<string, string> dict = 
        new Dictionary<String, String>();

    foreach (DataRow dr in sqlResults.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        dict.Add(
            dr.Field<string>("key").Trim(), dr.Field<string>("value").Trim()
                );
    }

    return dict;
}
```

Comment: So when iterating all results, do you see output `Key = EnableLdap Value = ...`?

Comment: I strongly suspect you don't have `"EnableLdap"` as a key, but something that looks *very similar*. Try printing out the length of each key when you iterate over it... you may find there's something like whitespace or invisible characters in there.

Comment: Might help to show the output from the foreach loop. Its possible you're just making a spelling error?

Comment: Remember that .NET is case sensitive by default and that invisible characters also matter

Comment: ...as does leading/trailing space, for instance, if the column is a `CHAR(20)` vs. a `VARCHAR(20)` on the database

Comment: side note: that last code snippit you provided that uses `TryGetValue` is the most efficient use of retrieving values in a dictionary when there is not a guarantee at run time that the key can be found.

Comment: Tim Schemlter was right. I ended up with whitespace trailing my key names. I'm not sure why, but I added a .Trim()  to my LoadConfiguration method and that fixed it. Facepalm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is one of these 2 issues.

1. The key does not exist in the dictionary, this could be due to a spelling mistake or even a leading/trailing space or something of that nature.
2. The key exists but is cased differently than you think it is.

For option 2 you can ensure that casing is not an issue by providing a `StringComparer` to the dictionary as an argument in the constructor.

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<String, String>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

The above code snippet will ensure that the dictionary creates the hash for each key based on the ordinal case insensitive representation of the string key. This will allow for the following example to pass:

```
dict["enableldap"] = "true";
Console.WriteLine(dict["EnableLdap"]);
```

See [StringComparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer(v=vs.110).aspx) for more options.

Comment: Trailing spaces were it.

Comment: @SergeHarrison - glad you got it working! To be safe you can always add your key using `Trim` to make sure its not an issue. (`dr.Field<string>("key").Trim()`)

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. I'm not sure why the SQL query is returning trailing spaces in my DataSet though but that definitely resolves the immediate issue.

Comment: @SergeHarrison - good  deal! Side note: depending on the size of the dictionary though it still might not be a bad idea to specify the `StrimComparer` to use. This can give it a performance boost if its rather large. See https://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary-stringcomparer for more details (*not my blog or anything*).

Answer (score 1):

*My understanding is that both the following methods would be correct. But when I try this way, I get a KeyNotFoundException*

It seems that your dictionary doesn't have that key. Keep in mind that dictionaries are key-sensitive you can check if a key exist by using this method:

```
Console.WriteLine("Exist key "+ dict.ContainsKey("EnableLdap"));
```

*If I try this I get a [InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element]*

```
  Dictionary<string,string> dict = MyStuff.Configuration.LoadConfiguration();
    Console.WriteLine(dict.Single(s => s.Key == "EnableLdap").Value);
```

The linQ method `.Single` expects to find a value. If no value is found that Exception will be thrown. You should be using `.SingleOrDefault` if you don't want that exception, but beware of nulls.

*And if I try this I just get nothing*.

TryGetValue doesn't throw any exceptions. It just tries.

I'd suggest you to add a format for your keys either uppercased or lowercased, when you're creating the dictionary.

```
foreach (DataRow dr in sqlResults.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            dict.Add(
                dr.Field<string>("key").ToUpperCase(), dr.Field<string>("value")
                    );
        }
```

and then you can query it like this:

```
if(dict.ContainsKey("ENABLELDAP"))
{
   string value = dict["ENABLELDAP"];
}
```